# How to find the interval for $x$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have two inequalities of the form:

$$⌊x⌋≤a$$ and $$⌊x⌋>b$$

My **question** is: How to find the interval for $x$ without using the symbol $⌊x⌋$. I have no idea to start.

Comment: Hint: Create few example to understand how floor and ceiling functions work. For example, if a=2.5, then x can be up to 3 (excluded). So, interval for x would be x<3, or in terms of a, x<floor(a)+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fraction part of areal number $\;\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor\;$, write:

$$b<\lfloor x\rfloor =x-\{x\}\le a\implies x\in\left(b+\{x\},\,a+\{x\}\right)$$

Of course, you have the symbol $\;\{\}\;$ , but I don't think you'll be able to get rid of both symbols without restricting more either of $\;x\,,\,\,a\,,\,\,b\;$ .

Comment: You can conclude $x\in (b, a+1)$ though.

Comment: @Macavity ...or in $\;(-\infty,\,\infty)\;$ for that matter. If the OP wanted an interval with integer end points I agree.

Comment: Ok, not worth a long debate, but given any feasible reals $a, b$ the possible values $x$ can take are given in the tightest possible explicit interval $(b,a+1)$, which I though was the point to the question.